# Rails webpacker is loading a previously deleted controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I created a controller, added some code, deleted that controller.

Now on every page I get console errors regarding the errors in the code in the  deleted controller.

Restarted the server and rebooted my development server.

How do you force the manifest to reload?  I thought this was automatic?

Answer (score 0):

i have encounted same problem...run

> ./bin/webpack --watch